# LSTM Neural Network Input/Output dimensions error

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, lstm

I am fairly new to TensorFlow and LSTM architecture. I have an issue with figuring out input and output (x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test) for my dataset.

Original shapes of my inputs:

- x_train: (366,4)
- x_test: (104,4)
- y_train: (366,)
- y_test: (104,)

The y_train and y_test are a series of stock prices. The x_train and x_test are four features that I want to use to predict the stock prices.

```
# Splitting the training and testing data

train_start_date = '2010-01-08'
train_end_date = '2017-01-06'
test_start_date = '2017-01-13'
test_end_date = '2019-01-04'

train = df.ix[train_start_date : train_end_date]
test = df.ix[test_start_date:test_end_date]


X_test = sentimentScorer(test)
X_train = sentimentScorer(train)

Y_test = test['prices'] 
Y_train = train['prices']

#Conversion in 3D array for LSTM INPUT

X_test = X_test.reshape(1, 104, 4)
X_train = X_train.reshape(1, 366, 4)





model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(366,4), activation='relu', 
return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(LSTM(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))

model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6)

# Compile model
model.compile(
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer=opt,
    metrics=['accuracy'],
)

model.fit(X_train,
          Y_train,
          epochs=3,
          validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
```

This is the error generated:

```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-101-fd4099583529> in <module>
>      65           Y_train,
>      66           epochs=3,
> ---> 67           validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
> 
> c:\users\talal\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py
> in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks,
> validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight,
> sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps,
> **kwargs)    1507         steps_name='steps_per_epoch',    1508         steps=steps_per_epoch,
> -> 1509         validation_split=validation_split)    1510     1511     # Prepare validation data.
> 
> c:\users\talal\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py
> in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight,
> batch_size, check_steps, steps_name, steps, validation_split)
>     991       x, y = next_element
>     992     x, y, sample_weights = self._standardize_weights(x, y, sample_weight,
> --> 993                                                      class_weight, batch_size)
>     994     return x, y, sample_weights
>     995 
> 
> c:\users\talal\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py
> in _standardize_weights(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight,
> batch_size)    1110         feed_input_shapes,    1111        
> check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch size.
> -> 1112         exception_prefix='input')    1113     1114     if y is not None:
> 
> c:\users\talal\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_utils.py
> in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis,
> exception_prefix)
>     314                            ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have ' +
>     315                            str(len(shape)) + ' dimensions, but got array '
> --> 316                            'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
>     317         if not check_batch_axis:
>     318           data_shape = data_shape[1:]
> 
> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_18_input to have
> 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (366, 4)
```

Comment: is 366 is the number of timestamps in one sample?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is almost fine.

Your `y_test` and `y_train` should be an array with one element or array of shape (1,1), it doesn't matter.

Your input shape is wrong though, first LSTM should be:

```
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(None,4), activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
```

Notice `None`, as your test and train sequences length are different, you cannot specify it (and Keras accepts first dimension unspecified). Error was due to lengths of 366 and 104 respectively. If you want to use batches with RNNs you should perform zero-padding with `keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences`.

No need to specify `input_shape` with batch, rest of the network should be fine.

And if you are performing regression, not classification, as is the case probably, you should perform two last steps written by @Ankish Bansal, e.g. changing loss to `mean squared error` and making last layer output 1 value instead of 10.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. I must explain that I have 366 observation and 4 features. (366,4). This is before I reshape it into (1, 366, 4). At any rate, a altered the input_shape to (1, 366, 4), which resulted in the error:

>ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 3 and 2

Comment: Check my update, this should solve all your problems

Comment: yes that worked but I am still confused on how to reduce the y_test and y_train to a (1,1) array. It doesnt make sense, these are the prices of stock corresponding to each of the observations (366 in x_train and 104 in x_test).

this is the error produced: 

ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 1 input samples and 366 target samples.

Comment: You need different architecture for this tak and read up on LSTMs/RNNs and how they function. BTW. Mark correct answer to your question in order to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3):

1. LSTM expects input of dims as (num_examples, seq_length, input_dims), so there is one error in input.
2. You are predicting output of dimension 1, what your model output is 10. Try this.

   `model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))`
3. Also, you are predicting price, that is regression problem. But, you are using classification setting. Try this

   `model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mean_squared_error'])`

Comment: Thanks for your response. as far as the first change your mentioned, I only have one sample, an array of (366, 4). 4 features and 366 observations. so youre suggesting my input_shape should be = (1 , 366 ,4)? but that resulted in the error: ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 3 and 2

Answer (score 1):

your dimension is wrong for X_train.LSTM only accepts 3-dimensional inputs.you are saying that you have 4 features. Assuming that 366 is your number of timestamps for one sample, your input should be in (num_samples,366,4) shape
cheers :-)

Comment: I only have one sample, a array of (366, 4). 4 features and 366 observations. so youre suggesting my input_shape should be = (1 , 366 ,4)? but that resulted in the error:

ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 3 and 2

Comment: yes, that should be :-).previously the error was in the first LSTM layer now that has fixed. now the error is in the last dense layer.output of that dense layer is 3D but you are providing 1D.use Keras flatten layer to reduce the dimension

Comment: use model.summary() to see the output shapes of each layers then you will understand. also the last Dense layers output shape should be 1 for user case use model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu')) for the last layer

Comment: the error seems to occur at the first LSTM layer:

" model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(1, 366,4), activation='relu', 
return_sequences=True)) "

Comment: @TalalZahid Check my updated answer, sorry for pointing in wrong direction yesterday, my bad.